# delay(0) causing code coverage issue with jasmine

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine, karma-runner

When trying  to unit test the following case, the code is not getting 100% code coverage. But when I remove the delay(0) it worked. But in that case angular casuing some issue like

> ***'ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current
>   value: 'ngIf: true''***

How should I change the code to get the 100% code coverage test without this console issue ?

### Angular Code

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
this.loaderService.getLoader$
  .pipe(delay(0),skip(1),takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
  .subscribe(loaderObj => {
    let isEnabled = false;
    this.loaderApis.forEach(loaderApi => {
      let filterobj = loaderObj.filter(z => z.apiEndPoints == loaderApi)[0];
      if (filterobj.isLoaderEnabled) {
        isEnabled = true;
        return;
      }
    });
    this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
  });
```

}

### Unit test

```
`const loaderApiList: Loader[] = [{ apiEndPoints: API_URLS.ACCOUNT, isLoaderEnabled: true },
{ apiEndPoints: API_URLS.STATEMENT_MONTH_LIST, isLoaderEnabled: false }];
component.loaderApis = loaderList;
loaderService.loaderList = loaderApiList;

fixture.detectChanges();
loaderSubj.next(loaderApiList);
expect(component.loaderApis).toEqual(loaderList);`
```

Comment: It is plausible that your unit test suite runs the test entrypoint and then checks for result(s), therefore adding async operations causes it to perform the rest of the tests and count up totals before it could get back to your promises. See if there is anything that would let you hint that the test is done when you say it's done.

Comment: I would try ro fix the Angular issue first. The error message is telling you that in your html you have an expression `*ngIf` which is evaluated to `false` first and then is synchronously evaluated to `true` in `ngAfterViewInit`. Why are you putting your logic in `ngAfterViewInit and not in ngOnInit`? Does `this.loaderService.getLoader$` emit asynchrnously? [This article](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/) explains in detail what you have to do to understand and fix the problem